# How to call POST API without form-data in ionic3?

Tags: ionic3, form-data

Hi I have triggered the POST api without headers but our API is called properly but got above error wrong parameter every time,but in the PostMan  it working tell m, anyone, what’s the problem in my code?**

```js
//hgome page
  goToContinue() {
    //
    var param = {
        code : this.uniqueCode
    }

   this.service.checkLogin(function(isSuccess, data) {
      //set the new page....
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('SliderPage'); 
   }, param)
  }
  
  ///service class
  checkLogin(callback : any, value : any) {

    this.http.
    post(https://ams.code.co.in/auth/checkschoolcode', value).subscribe((data:any) => {
      callback(true, data);
    },err => {
         console.log('ddd' +err);
    });
}
```

Comment: You may need some type of header if your using a REST API. What are you using for your back end?

Comment: Sir i am using REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Code:

`this.headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};
      this.http.post('your API URL', JSON.stringify('Your Data Variable'), {headers: this.headers})
       .map(res => res.json())
       .subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
      });`

Other wise you have native plugin for IONIC to call HTTP requests. 
[check this plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/)

Comment: sir but i don't pass the headers?

Comment: why don't you pass headers?

Comment: we have pass only data sir i  used above but i got error in the res.json() ?

Comment: check this tutorial: https://www.joshmorony.com/using-http-to-fetch-remote-data-from-a-server-in-ionic-2/

Comment: sir i have triggered API via above format but i got error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined ?

Comment: sir tell me one thing it is back-end or front end problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186198/discussion-between-kapil-soni-and-najam-us-saqib).